# Nslookup works but ping fails

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ping, ipv4

I've recently ran into this weird problem where the domain names fail to resolve from DNS. When I try to ping google.com, I get ping request could not find host google.com, but nslookup returns the correct ip address for google. Pinging any ip whether it be on the internet or local works perfectly fine, but any DNS resolution does not work including localhost. I've tried numerous things like resetting the TCP stack, disabling ipv6, ipconfig /flushdns, but they have all not worked.

This just randomly happened after a power loss. Upon turning the computer back on, domain names would not resolve and a few other oddities occurred like memory and cpu usage skyrocketing with the computer left on overnight.

I've completely uninstalled my antivirus, Bitdefender, the limit the possiblities.

I'm really confused as to how this happened. I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: it could be your router/modem.

Comment: I know its not my router or modem because I have several other devices(wired and wireless) that connect to the internet just fine. I also know it is not a hardware issue but a software issue because I have Windows 8 dual booting and it also connects correctly.

Comment: Can you post a ipconfig /all, lets confirm your network settings first